# Master Sync Database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Hi am syncing my database with server for any incremental values on click of a button. Below is the code which checks all the values and inserts if the data is missing but from android perspective is there any optimized technique to do the sync

```
//new fields

    public void updatenewfileds(ArrayList<String> s) {

        ArrayList<String> da = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            String manu = "select MANUFACTURERID from ManufacturerDesc";
            Cursor cc = mDb.rawQuery(manu,null);

            Log.d("Cursor count", "Count =" + cc.getCount());
            if (cc != null && cc.getCount() > 0) {
                if (cc.moveToFirst());
                do {
                    da.add(cc.getString(cc.getColumnIndex("MANUFACTURERID")));
                    System.out.println("here got all alreday avilable ids"+ cc.getString(cc.getColumnIndex("MANUFACTURERID")));
                } while (cc.moveToNext());
                cc.close();
            } else {
                cc.close();
            }
            // need to add only missing data
            for(int i = 0; i<da.size(); i++){               
                boolean flag = false;
                System.out.println(flag);
                for(int j=0; j<i; j++){
                    if(da.get(i).equals(s.get(i*2))){
                        flag = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

            if(flag  == false){
            String sql = "insert into ManufacturerDesc values('"+ s.get(i*2)+"','"+ s.get(i*2+1)+"');";
            System.out.println("item inserted into db"+ s.get(i*2) +"******" + s.get(i*2+1) );
            mDb.execSQL(sql);
            }
            }

        } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "getTestData >>" + mSQLException.toString());

            throw mSQLException;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Does this method receive receive the full database from server each time?

Comment: @cYrixmorten yes it checks the missing data and send it but it is checking full database everytime

Answer (score 2):

This would be my suggestion, the [] are just to emphasize, as I might get back to it:

- Design your Android database tables like: { _id, **[server_id]**, .. your data .. }
- On all your tables on the server add a **[time_changed]** timestamp.
- Whenever your device gets synced with the server, the server should additionally send a **last sync timestamp** e.g. System.currentTimeMilliseconds() (letting the server do this to avoid relying on synced clocks). This timestamp is stored on the android device and used whenever requesting a new sync.
- When the server receives a sync request the stored **last sync timestamp** is yet again handed to the server from the device. Now a simple query can extract all the relevant added data since the timestamp (minus some constant to ensure you get everything). For example SELECT * FROM Mydata WHERE (time_changed > (last_sync-5000)); 5000 being 5 seconds.
- Now as you receive data from the server, remember to add the **[server_id]**, which is just the autoincremented _id from the server. This enables you to deduce whether some of thee received rows are known (which is likely with the minus 5 seconds above).
- The deduction is a simple query on the device e.g: Do I already have a row with **[server_id]**, if not we add it, if yes then skip it.

With this method you avoid to send more and more information over time, as you only send the rows that are changed after the last sync (plus a bit more).

If you edit rows on your server, simply update **time_changed** again to reflect the edit . Then it will automatically be included and overwritten on the device during the next sync.

If you plan on doing a lot of database operations on the android device, I would suggest trying [MotoDev](http://sourceforge.net/projects/motodev.motorola/files/), it can be plugged in to eclipse and has some nice database features. Including a database perspective and automatic generation of ContentProviders (nice classes to make database operations simple).

Giving a full explanation or guide to do all this is way out of the scope of this answer. It should merely give you an idea as to how it can be done, and if you wish to improve your syncing process, you now have some guidance.

Regarding mechanism as autoincrement and timestamp on a database, there is plenty of examples to find on the interwebz.

Happy coding :)

Comment: @cYrixmoten Yes but do you haave any tutorial to do that pl

Comment: What part of it? I am sorry by the way but will not be able to complete my answer before aprox. 3,5 hours from now. Will get back to it.

Comment: Introducing time stamp and doing incremental datas to get added @cYrixmoten

Comment: the _id is usually automatically added, as I recall, in Android. I do not know what database you use on the server but they all usually have an Integer autoincrement function as well as a automatic timestamp on add or update.